# Why table id is not identified by getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to get the id of my table and calculate the number of rows in my table.
I used this code

```
var table =document.getElementById("test");
var i = table.rows.length;
```

This doesnot work for me when I use window.onload It works. This my working function

```
window.onload = function() {
var table =document.getElementById("test");
var i = table.rows.length;

}
```

Now I need this `i` variable used in another function. How to make this `i` variable global. Any problem with my code?
Can some one help me code?
**Edit 01**

```
<table id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;"><img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/employee.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:35px;"><img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/start_time.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:35px;"><img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/id.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:145px;"><img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/Description.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;"><img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/Type.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/qty_prch.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/qty_used.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/Price.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/discount.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/Tax.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/assets/img/ticket_page/Total_01.svg"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="employee[]" value="" style="width:80px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="pid[]" onChange="get_values(this.value)" value="" style="width:35px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description[]" id="description1" value="" style="width:145px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="type[]" id="type1" style="width:45px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty_prch[]" id="qty_prch1" style="width:45px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty_used[]" id="qty_used1" style="width:45px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" style="width:70px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="discount[]" id="discount1" style="width:70px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax1" style="width:70px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="total[]" id="total1" style="width:70px;" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to use that variable `i` in this following javascript

```
 function displayResult()
        {


            document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="employee[]" value="" style="width:80px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" onChange="get_values(this.value)" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description[x]" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" id="type[x]" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" id="qty_used[x]" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value=""  style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value=""  style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value=""  style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value=""  style="width:70px;"/></td>';
        }
function get_values(val)
{

    $.ajax({
         url: baseurl+'admin/billing/getdetails',
         type: 'post',
         data : {val:val},
         success: function (response) {    
            if(response!="")
            {
                var json=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $('#description1').val(json.description);
                $('#type1').val(json.type); 
                $('#qty_used1').val(json.cost);                             
            }
         },
         error: function(response){
            alert("error");
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: its not a good practice to use global variables. can you show your html as well?

Comment: Yeah.. Not a good practice.. No Globals please.. Please pass it as a variable to the function that needs it

Comment: Is there some other way to do it? I need to get my table row count and use it in my function

Comment: Why you need numbered ids?

Comment: Using that id I need to pass a value to my controller which sends a json response only when i know my correct row i could place my json response in that correct row

Comment: Just "pin" the index of the submitted row in the success handler `$.getJSON(/*...*/, function(rowIndex, response){ var submittedRow = $("#test tr:nth-child(" + (rowIndex + 1) + ")"); }.bind(window, <indexOfTheRowSubmitted>)`

Comment: Can you please brief it I am new to these concept... @Andreas

Comment: I've added a little more text (-> answer) to explain my concept in more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would slightly change the setup... :)

1. Change all the numbered ids to unnumbered classes (also in the `displayResult` function)

```
id="description1" --> class="description"
id="type1" --> class="type"
...
```

```
function displayResult() {
    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="employee[]" value="" style="width:80px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
```

2. Remove the "onChange" attribute from the newly inserted row and instead use a "global" change handler on the table using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - (methods used in the change handler:  [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/))

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').on('change', 'input[name="pid[]"]', function() {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(this.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});
```

3. Change the signature of `get_values()` to accept an additional parameter - the index of the changed row

```
function get_values(val, rowIndex) {
    //...
}
```

4. Change the success handler of the ajax call to use the new layout

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + 'admin/billing/getdetails',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        val: val
    },
    success: function (indexOfTheChangedRow, response) {
        if (response != "") {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response),
                rowToUpdate = $("#test tr:nth-child(" + (indexOfTheChangedRow + 1) + ")");

            // add the changed row as the context to restrict the search for the classes to this one row only
            $('.description', rowToUpdate).val(json.description);
            $('.type', rowToUpdate).val(json.type);
            $('.qty_used', rowToUpdate).val(json.cost);
        }
    }.bind(window, rowIndex),
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I'm using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to "pin" the clicked row index to this ajax request (the success handler).

Now you can add as many rows as you want and you won't have to mess around with numbered ids :)

Comment: Really glad with your explanation. I will tryout now :)

Comment: @Anu I'm glad to hear that and have fun experimenting ;)

Comment: Can I have a dropdown box instead of first textbox? form_dropdown?@Andreas

Comment: Sure. Did you encounter any problems with it or what's the reason for the question?

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything stopping you from having this other function inside the `onload` closure as well?

```
window.onload = function() {

    var table = document.getElementById("test"),
        i = table.rows.length,

        doStuff = function () {
            // has access to i
        },

        doMoreStuff = function () {
            // also has access to i
        },

        get_values = function () {
            // also has access to i
        };

    document.getElementsByName("pid[]")[0].addEventListener("change", get_values);
}
```

Edit: You can remove your `onChange` attribute from the HTML and add an event handler in your JavaScript

Comment: When I have a function onchange="get_values()" inside window.onload It does not work. :(

Comment: @Anu can you show that code too? I don't see that in your question

Comment: You need the get_value() ? I will post now

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the scope of variable as global.

```
var i = null;
window.onload = function() {
  var table =document.getElementById("test");
  i = table.rows.length;
}
```

Comment: Dear @Milind we are trying to make users aware of a few facts (Not using Globals, in this case) can you please make sure that you do not answer with such codes?

Comment: user can not achieve this when both functions have different context. other solution would be to get the table and find rows again. which is definitely not a good approach compared to defining context as global.

Comment: Oh.. Even with different Context you definitely can pass the variables I think.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: yes but op is not calling the method from onload  method. also i did not said its unavoidable. i said not feasible over other approach in this case

Comment: Is there some other way to get table row count and use them in other function? getElementById works only when they are in window.onload()

Comment: @Anu: the reason you need load or ready is to ensure the code to be executed when dom is loaded/ready. the reason first part of your code did not worked because element is not there when ` document.getElementById("test")` is used to get that object.

Comment: can I use ready instead of this? Is that possible? @MilindAnantwar

Comment: Instead of making things global is there safe way to access those variable?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Now I agree with the answer here.. But not about the suggested approach. Why can the OP not change her approach? She definitely can. Its a very simple use case here..

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: forget it. the variable being used here is row count which can be used globally. not going to hamper the functionality nor its unsafe in terms of security. there is no point in complicating the code for such simple things.

Comment: what if i write a function to modify `i = "blah!"` What do you think? Will it or not break the funcitonality?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: that way variable is defined globally. which is nothing but first point i raised already